# curly braces problem (garamondx package)

Tags: errors, brackets

Sorry. i couldn't see another question about this. I'm using garamondx package. The problem is large curly bracket. It seems like the picture given. i want stg like { , but that's like ( .
what can i do?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\{f(x)= \left\{ \begin{cases}
  & 1 \\ 
 & 2 \\ 
 & 3 \\ 
\end{cases} \right.$ \\

$W(A,B)=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    0 \quad \text{se $n$=0 ed $m$=0}\\
    \infty \quad \text{se $n$=0 o $m$=0}\\

  \end{array} \right.$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you provided a MWE so we can see exactly what you're doing to produce these results.

Comment: Please add the code as text, select it and click the {} button, that way we can copy-paste it.

Comment: Remove the `\DeclareSymbolfont` and `\DeclareMathAlphabet` commands. They are plainly wrong, as you want to use Garamond and not Times, don't you?

Comment: when i write those, i see numbers from Times and letters from Garamond. Actually i tried and removing them changed nothing except numbers. so i preferred it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wrong symbol is a consequence of

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
```

because `newtxmath` uses a different encoding for its `largesymbols` font, namely `LMX` as one can see from the declaration

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
```

found in `newtxmath.sty`. In the same file we see

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{lettersA}{163}{largesymbols}{138}
```

whereas, for an `OMX` encoded font, one has

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{largesymbols}{"08}
```

So the slot used in an `OMX` font is different from the one used in `LMX`. The  `yhex` font has a closing parentheses in slot 138, whence what you're experiencing.

One should note that the `yhex` font is an extension of `cmex`, which is not visually compatible with any form of Garamond, while the `garamondx` option for `newtxmath` is not visually clashing (or, at least, it's less visually clashing).

Remove also

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
```

because you *don't* really want to have Times characters in a Garamond based document. Also `amsfonts` and `amssymb` are not needed, because `newtxmath` replaces them anyway.

Here's a working version of your document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 3 \\
\end{cases}
\\
W(A,B)=\begin{cases}
  0 & \text{se $n$=0 ed $m$=0}\\
  \infty & \text{se $n$=0 o $m$=0}
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]